# message deleted from queue

Tags: activemq-classic, blockingqueue

I have used BlockingQueue implementation to process my events by services from a queue. However in case if the server goes down, all my events from that queue are getting deleted and hence I am missing events to process. (I am looking for some internal DB where server can store the event/messages from queue and if server goes down and up again, it can load all events/messages to process again, without manually intervention).

Any help on this. I am not sure if I should use Apache ActiveMQ. I am using apache servicemix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not answer about how to do this with BlockingQueue.

But ActiveMQ has two features that you will benefit from:

[Persistent Queues](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-difference-between-persistent-and-non-persistent-delivery.html) and possibly you might also want to look at [Durable Queues](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html)

It has a built in database that just does this under the hood and allows messages to be persisted in queue even if broker or consumer has to restart.

Comment: by default activemq uses kahadb to persist the messages in temp db so that if server crashes it can restore all the messages. there is setting that needs to be done in activemq.xml file.